# Por que getElementsByClassName não funciona sem o for?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tava criando um menu que tinha dois botoes, uma mostrasse aba de descricao e outra mostrasse aba da ficha tecnica.

criei uma funcao no javascript que ao clicar no botao o ***display*** de um seria ***none*** e outro ***block***.

fiz o seguinte:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick='funcao("tec","des")'>Descricao</button>
<button onclick='funcao("des","tec")'>Tecnico</button>


<div class="des">
   <p>
      Isso eh uma descricao
   </p>
</div>

<div class="tec">
   <p>
      isso eh uma ficha tecnica
   </p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function funcao(desaparece, aparece){
var desa, apar;

desa = document.getElementsByClassName(desaparece);
apar = document.getElementsByClassName(aparece);

desa.style.display = 'none';
apar.style.display = 'block';
}
```

mas nao estava funcionando pesquisei um pouco fiz outra funcao:

```
function funcao(desaparece, aparece){
     var desa, apar;

     desa = document.getElementsByClassName(desaparece);
     apar = document.getElementsByClassName(aparece);

     for (i = 0; i < desa.length; i++) {
         desa[i].style.display = "none";
     }

     for (i = 0; i < apar.length; i++) {
         apar[i].style.display = "block";
     }
}
```

e esse funcionou , mas nao consigo entender porque um funcionou e outro nao.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `getElementsByClassName` retorna uma lista, isso está na documentação:

> The `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` method, when invoked, must return the list of elements with class names *classNames* for *this*.

> A call to `document.getElementById("example").getElementsByClassName("aaa")` would return a **HTMLCollection**.

Fonte: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname

Sobre o *HTMLCollection* (o "array" retornado pelo `getElementsByClassName`), é especificado que:

> - `collection . length`:
>   Returns the number of elements in the collection.
> - `element = collection . item(index)` or `element = collection[index]`:
>   Returns the element with index index from the collection. The elements are sorted in tree order.
> - `element = collection . namedItem(name)` or `element = collection[name]`:
>   Returns the first element with ID or name name from the collection.

Fonte: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection.

---

Sendo assim, sempre que utiliza o `getElementsByClassName` você vai obter um `HTMLCollection`, que é similar à uma lista, um array. Então, para acessar cada um dos items desta lista, você deve utilizar `collection[index]` ou `collection.item(index)`.

---

No caso você não precisa utilizar o `for` já que existe apenas um único elemento. No caso de SÓ EXISTIR um único elemento com a classe, você poderia utilizar:

```
desa = document.getElementsByClassName(desaparece)[0];
apar = document.getElementsByClassName(aparece)[0];
```

O `[0]` irá obter o primeiro item de tal lista (do HTMLCollection). Entretanto, para casos gerais, assumindo que possa existir multiplos elementos com o a mesma classe você precisará utilizar o  `for` (ou qualquer outra forma similar).

Isso foi o que você fez, e foi o que funcionou:

```
 for (i = 0; i < desa.length; i++) {
     desa[i].style.display = "none";
 }

 for (i = 0; i < apar.length; i++) {
     apar[i].style.display = "block";
 }
```

Dessa forma, primeiro você usa o `desa.length`/`apar.length` (que é o `collection.length`) para saber o seu limite, e obtem cada item usando o `desa[i]`/`apar[i]` (que é o `collection[index]`).